# How to save as a "Plain SVG" using Makefile with Inkscape

Tags: image, svg, makefile, inkscape

Using `--verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit` in the make file saves the SVG as a *Inkscape SVG* with a lot of Inkscape window viewing information.

I am trying to get rid of it in-order to reduce the file size by saving as *Plain SVG* however there seem to be no specific [VERB-ID](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/inkscape-man.html) to do this.

What modification do i need to make to the script so that I can get rid of the extra information in SVGs when genrating them?

Comment: This isn't in any way related to Makefiles

Comment: If there isn't a way to tell inkscape what format to use to save the file via the command line then you can't do it this way. But you should be able to post-process the file to remove anything you want with some other svg or xml tool I would imagine.

Comment: @EtanReisner That's my plan B thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Why do you think so? @AnalPhabet

Comment: @Ashesh The only vague remark about Makefiles is that it's used as a build/scripting system, not as a primary concern of the question

Comment: Do you mean `inkscape --export-plain-svg=result.svg`?

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: No, after generating the inkscape SVGs I am actually running another script to export them as plain SVGs using `inkscape --export-plain-svg=result.svg` as you mentioned above. An extra step but works.

Answer (score 7):

Just use the option `--export-plain-svg` of the inkscape to choose the output type.

```
inkscape --export-plain-svg=output.svg input.svg
```

See other options with:

```
inkscape --help
```

Additionally you can optimize the svg using the [`svgo`](https://github.com/svg/svgo) tool:

```
svgo output.svg
```

**Full scenario**: you have a svg file called `road.svg` and want another one called `road-plain.svg`.

**A sample makefile:**

```
%-plain.svg: %.svg
    inkscape --export-plain-svg=$@ $<
    svgo $@

all: road-plain.svg
```

The output:

```
$ make all

inkscape --export-plain-svg=road-plain.svg road.svg
svgo road-plain.svg

road-plain.svg:
Done in 101 ms!
3.102 KiB - 49.4% = 1.57 KiB
```

Resulting in a plain and optmized svg file!

Comment: Since this is the first result for looking up "export-plain-svg" for Inkscape, i'll post this here: in Inkscape 1.0.2, the above command will raise "`Warning: Option --export-plain-svg= is deprecated`"; the changed command should be now: `inkscape "$MYFILE" --export-plain-svg --export-type=svg --export-filename=temp` - but not that `.svg` will be automatically appended to the output file name, if not already there!